# Safe, standard way to load images in ListView on a different thread?

Tags: android, listview, multithreading, imageview, android-asynctask

Before making this question, I have searched and read these ones:
[Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview)
[Android - Issue with lazy loading images into a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409623/android-issue-with-lazy-loading-images-into-a-listview)

My problem is I have a `ListView`, where:

- Each row contains an `ImageView`, whose
  content is to be loaded from the
  internet
- Each row's view is recycled as in
  ApiDemo's List14

What I want ultimately:

- Load images lazily, only when the user
  scrolls to them
- Load images on different thread(s) to
  maintain responsiveness

My current approach:

- In the adapter's `getView()` method, apart from
  setting up other child views, I launch a
  new thread that loads the Bitmap from
  the internet. When that loading thread
  finishes, it returns the `Bitmap` to be set on the `ImageView` (I do this using `AsyncTask` or `Handler`).
- Because I recycle `ImageView`s, it may
  be the case that I first want to set
  a view with `Bitmap#1`, then later want
  to set it to `Bitmap#2` when the user
  scrolls down. `Bitmap#1` may happen to
  take longer than `Bitmap#2` to load, so
  it may end up overwriting `Bitmap#2` on
  the view. I solve this by maintaining
  a `WeakHashMap` that remembers the last `Bitmap` I want
  to set for that view.

Below is somewhat a pseudocode for my current approach. I've ommitted other details like caching, just to keep the thing clear.

```
public class ImageLoader {

    // keeps track of the last Bitmap we want to set for this ImageView
    private static final WeakHashMap<ImageView, AsyncTask> assignments
                                    = new WeakHashMap<ImageView, AsyncTask>();

    /** Asynchronously sets an ImageView to some Bitmap loaded from the internet */
    public static void setImageAsync(final ImageView imageView, final String imageUrl) {
        // cancel whatever previous task
        AsyncTask oldTask = assignments.get(imageView);
        if (oldTask != null) {
            oldTask.cancel(true);
        }

        // prepare to launch a new task to load this new image
        AsyncTask<String, Integer, Bitmap> newTask = new AsyncTask<String, Integer, Bitmap>() {

            protected void onPreExecute() {
                // set ImageView to some "loading..." image
            }

            protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
                return loadFromInternet(imageUrl);
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
                // set Bitmap if successfully loaded, or an "error" image
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } else {
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.error);
                }
            }
        };
        newTask.execute();

        // mark this as the latest Bitmap we want to set for this ImageView
        assignments.put(imageView, newTask);
    }

    /** returns (Bitmap on success | null on error) */
    private Bitmap loadFromInternet(String imageUrl) {}
}
```

Problem I still have: what if the Activity gets destroyed while some images are still loading?

- Is there any risk when the loading
  thread calls back to the ImageView
  later, when the Activity is already
  destroyed?
- Moreover, `AsyncTask` has some global
  thread-pool underneath, so if lengthy
  tasks are not canceled when they're
  not needed anymore, I may end up
  wasting time loading things users
  don't see. My current design of
  keeping this thing globally is too
  ugly, and may eventually cause some
  leaks that are beyond my
  understanding. Instead of making
  `ImageLoader` a singleton like this,
  I'm thinking of actually creating
  separate `ImageLoader` objects for
  different `Activities`, then when an
  `Activity` gets destroyed, all its
  `AsyncTask` will be canceled. Is this
  too awkward?

Anyway, I wonder if there is a safe and standard way of doing this in Android. In addition, I don't know iPhone but is there a similar problem there and do they have a standard way to do this kind of task?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I solve this by maintaining a
>   WeakHashMap that remembers the last
>   Bitmap I want to set for that view.

I took the approach attaching the the URL of the desired image onto the `ImageView` via `setTag()`. Then, when I have the image downloaded, I double-check the `ImageView` URL -- if it is different than the one I just downloaded, I don't update the `ImageView`, because it got recycled. I just cache it.

> Is there any risk when the loading
>   thread calls back to the ImageView
>   later, when the Activity is already
>   destroyed?

I am not aware of any risk, other than a bit of wasted CPU time and bandwidth (and, hence, battery).

> Instead of making ImageLoader a
>   singleton like this, I'm thinking of
>   actually creating separate ImageLoader
>   objects for different Activities, then
>   when an Activity gets destroyed, all
>   its AsyncTask will be canceled. Is
>   this too awkward?

Canceling an `AsyncTask` is not terribly easy, if it is already running. I'd just let it run to completion.

Ideally, avoid singletons. Either use a `Service`, or pass your `ImageLoader` to the next instance of your activity via `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` (e.g., `isFinishing()` is `false` in `onDestroy()`, so this is a rotation).

Comment: I'm doing something similar, although just using Thread and Handler.  The problem comes when the user flings the list...many threads get spawn and eventually Android force closes the Activity. So, I use an mThread member variable and interrupt it in bindView of my adapter. But for some reason, these threads stop getting called after the listview gets a fling.  In debug mode, everything is so slow that the problem doesn't happen, so I can't figure out why it stops working. Did you have a method for preventing many threads from spawning in a fling?