# Load Splash Screen from a Web server Android App

Tags: android, android-layout, cordova

Would it be possible to use an image from the webserver as slash screen. I would like to specify the splash screen from an url not as a local file. Or Would it be possible to download an image dynamically from a webserver and replace the current splash screen ?

Comment: ya its possible but purpose of splash is not that ...

Comment: How can I do that ? Do not want to load all the time but it would be better if it can be downloaded once in a week and replace the old splash screen. Thanks in advance

Comment: It would be better not to have a splash screen at all. Display something useful and lazy load anything else. The quicker the app starts the more likely users will stick with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the some tricks for making splash scree using image, which is download form server.

First download image from server,this tutorials

http://getablogger.blogspot.com/2008/01/android-download-image-from-server-and.html

then set that downloaded image on splash screen

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends Activity {

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.splash);

 // Set Image download from server, which is already defined above link.

  /** set time to splash out */
final int welcomeScreenDisplay = 3000;
/** create a thread to show splash up to splash time */
Thread welcomeThread = new Thread() {

int wait = 0;

@Override
public void run() {
try {
super.run();
/**
* use while to get the splash time. Use sleep() to increase
* the wait variable for every 100L.
*/
while (wait < welcomeScreenDisplay) {
sleep(100);
wait += 100;
}
} catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println("EXc=" + e);
} finally {
/**
* Called after splash times up. Do some action after splash
* times up. Here we moved to another main activity class
*/
startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this,
MainScreenActivity.class));
finish();
}
}
};
welcomeThread.start();

}
}
```

More information about getting image from server:

[Load images from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009092/load-images-from-url)

and

some code for making splash screen

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/113831/An-Advanced-Splash-Screen-for-Android-App

Answer (score 0):

Have a default splash screen image built into the app so that there is no delay in displaying it when the app is first run. The app should certainly start quicker than you can download a picture over a mobile connection.

At some point, download the new image in a background thread and store it somewhere, possibly on the SD card if it is large.

Then display this image instead of the default. Repeat this weekly as you want a new image each week.

Or, preferably, just speed up the launch so you don't need a splash screen at all.

Comment: How can I download and store Since am very new to this platform ?